# modification date / date asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I pay attention to the active question queue. Posts there are marked with the modification date, which is always essentially "now" since this is the active question queue. I would rather see the date when the question was asked. I could use that information to decide whether it was worth my time looking.

Implementing this would not use any screen real estate, since there is already a date there.

I think this feature makes equal sense for all the stackexchange sites.

Comment: Meta.stackexchange is the place to ask for changes to how the machinery of SE runs.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261203/include-original-ask-date-on-active-tab for example...

Comment: @JonCuster Correct advice and a very useful link to an essential duplicate. Post as an answer (even though link only answers are discouraged) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests to change how the machinery of the site work are handled on  Meta.stackexchange.

Now, not surprisingly, this has been requested before over there, such as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261203/include-original-ask-date-on-active-tab). The answer there points to a user script that can be installed to add the 'asked' date. Now, whether that script still works or not I will leave up to others - I'm not a fan of downloading code on my work machine.